# Addthis Button customize sharing details

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, addthis

I am trying to use addThis button to share my page on facebook through like button, I want to edit the title, description and image displayed on the newsfeed on facebook. I have created a jsFiddle for my work. It works but the details are wrong. What could be the problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/UYVDK/1/

Comment: AFAIK the only way to alter title and description is by adding FB specific meta tags to the page. AddThis overrides don't work.

Comment: so shall I delete them and add fb meta tags to the page?

Comment: FB meta tags will get you custom title and desc in FB, but wont help with the other two. You may have to either be ok with that or make custom methods for posting. We handle the twitter changes via a custom function which calls their 'share' API (doesn't go via addthis).

Comment: So I can not edit the shared image? What do you mean?

Comment: I have tried adding meta tags still no luck, http://jsfiddle.net/UYVDK/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing like this is not possible with jsFiddle as the meta tags are outside of the `<head>`

See this link: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2FUYVDK%2F4%2Fshow

You will need access to a real page where you have control over the `<head>` section and put the correct og meta tags (see http://ogp.me) so Facebook can lint it properly.